# Help needed for rephrasing closed question

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1704911/differences-between-fido2-usb-doggles) about differences between different FIDO2 USB dongles. Although it might sound like a product recommendation on the surface it's actually general security related question not limited to a specific product (which I even noted at the end of the question).

I get why this might be mistaken for a product recommendation but unfortunately there was no further comment. So a little bit of help on how this question could be rephrased would be appreciated very much. Thanks!

Comment: You might not be *asking* for a product, but essentially the only real question is "should I spend $25 for one thing or $50 for another." If both products are ostensibly the same then only the manufacturers can explain what theirs is supposed to do that makes it worth more. Asking us to seek out information to compare two products also kind of falls back to product recommendations.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks, the price point is just the range of prices, USB dongles are sold for, it's not just 25 and 50 it's everything in between as well. Also I'm not asking if I should buy a 25 or a 50, my actual question is, if there are differences between dongles that are compatible with the FIDO2 standard (regardless of the price). I thought it's helpful adding the general price range, but if not I can remove it as well.

Comment: The other problem is that if you start at the assumption that all the products are *functionally* identical, then all they really vary in is non-functional things. You may well simply be buying a "brand", different build quality, or even just different levels of support, and not anything that relevant to computer hardware or software in the context of this site. An M.2 SATA drive is absolutely functionally different to an M.2 NVMe, but two *functionally identical* devices is difficult to define. I get that is the crux of your question and that's why I left it alone when I originally saw it.

Comment: I'm rather asking about different "functionality" in regards to security issues with FIDO2. I could answer this question e.g. for "buying cheap IP-Cams". This can introduce security issues, and can be avoided by ...". Neither the question nor the answer would be a product recommendation or related to a specific product. But back to the point, would you have any recommendations on how to improve the question?

Comment: I'm thinking about rephrasing a question like "I have the FIDO2 key XYZ", do I have to expect any security issues...? Then it couldn't be confused with product recommendation any more but essentially it's the same content, it seem so superficial.

Comment: "do I have to expect any security issues...?" would likely get closed as opinion based.

Comment: @DavidPostill that is a good point, thank you.